# AlamofireObjectMapper.swift line 74 works in Playground but not on device or emulator

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

How can the following be working in Xcode Playground and not when running on device or emulator.

Alamofire is returning allright with everything. I can pass it with `.responseJSON` no problem.

But using `.responseObject` it fails [here in line 74](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/blob/b03ecca284d413225e0435d870da345d64458cc0/AlamofireObjectMapper/AlamofireObjectMapper.swift#L74) with `SIGABRT`

And the console says: `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`

Again, this is working from Playground with same classes and `Alamofire.request`

```
    Alamofire.request(
        url_planday_employees,
        method: .get,
        headers: headers_employees).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Items>) in
            // Error
            for item in (userResponse?.items)! {
                if let user = item.user {
                    print("Result in... user")
                    print("Name:" + user.name! )
                }
            }
    }
```

The Classes:

```
class User: Mappable {
    var name: String?
    var id: Int?

    required init?(map: Map){}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        id <- map["id"]
    }
}

class Item: Mappable {
    var user: User?

    required init?(map: Map){}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        user <- map["item"]
    }
}

class Items: Mappable {
    var items: [Item]?

    required init?(map: Map){}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        items <- map["items"]
    }
}
```

The JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
              {
              "item": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Anders And"
              }
              },
              {
              "item": {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Andersine"
              }
              }
              ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was about incompatibility issues between 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 of [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library.

Here is the related issues opened a while ago:

- https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/issues/179
- https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/722

For a quick fix, you can use the older version (2.2.1):

As for carthage here is how it is done:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.3.0
github "tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper" ~> 4.0.1
github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" == 2.2.1
```

**Update**

As of version 2.2.3, problem seems to be fixed:

```
github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" ~> 2.2.3
```